# I want VBScript to read CSV file and print in HTML table with conditional format

Tags: vbscript

I need VB script to read the text/csv file and print the data in html page with the table format. And I need to apply the condition to change the field color when the value cross above 200.

My Requirments:

1. VB script to read the csv/text (log parsed ) file and print the data in table format with in the html page
2. Need to apply conditional format to change the field color when AvgTime filed value cross above 200

Currently I am follwoing below method which is not supporting for conditional format.

1. Parsing IIS logs into CSV file, below is the output format (using `logparser`)

   ```
   Date,csUriStem,Hits,AvgTime,MaxTime,MinTime,Status    
   2014-11-14,/test/al/trmpaaaaresearch.aspx,24,57.625000,328,0,200.000000     
   2014-11-14,/test/al/trmalmaindets.aspx,335,217.677612,13593,15,200.000000    
   2014-11-14,/test/queuebulkapprove.aspx,64,862.875000,2281,0,200.000000    
   2014-11-14,/test/al/trmtestsearch.aspx,67,53.268657,296,0,200.000000
   ```
2. Parsing CSV file into text file, below is the output format (using `logparser`)

   ```
   '<tr><td>' Date       '</td><td>' csUriStem                       '</td><td>' Hits '</td><td>' AvgTime    '</td><td>' MaxTime '</td><td>' MinTime '</td><td>' Status     '</td></tr>'
   ---------- ---------- ----------- ------------------------------- ----------- ---- ----------- ---------- ----------- ------- ----------- ------- ----------- ---------- ------------
   <tr><td>   2014-11-14 </td><td>   /test/al/trmalmaindets.aspx      </td><td>   335  </td><td>   217.677612 </td><td>   13593   </td><td>   15      </td><td>   200.000000 </td></tr>    
   <tr><td>   2014-11-14 </td><td>   /test/queuebulkapprove.aspx      </td><td>   64   </td><td>   862.875000 </td><td>   2281    </td><td>   0       </td><td>   200.000000 </td></tr>    
   <tr><td>   2014-11-14 </td><td>   /test/al/trmtestsearch.aspx      </td><td>   67   </td><td>   53.268657  </td><td>   296     </td><td>   0       </td><td>   200.000000 </td></tr>
   ```
3. Using vbscript reading text file and print data in html file line line. Out put showing as attached 123.jpg ![htmlpage][1]
4. batch code:

   ```
   rem IIS logs parsing into CSV file
   C:\InfraLogsSync_dontdelete\Website_status\LogParser\LogParser.exe -i:iisw3c -o:csv "SELECT Min(TO_LOCALTIME(date)) AS Date, TO_LOWERCASE(cs-uri-stem) AS csUriStem, COUNT(*) AS Hits, DIV ( MUL(1.0, SUM(time-taken)), Hits ) AS AvgTime, Max(time-taken) AS MaxTime, Min(time-taken) AS MinTime, TO_REAL(STRCAT(TO_STRING(sc-status), STRCAT('.', TO_STRING(sc-substatus)))) AS Status INTO C:\InfraLogsSync_dontdelete\Website_status\Website_TimeTaken.csv FROM E:\Wlogs\W3SVC1755586166\ex*.log WHERE (TO_LOCALTIME(TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time)) >= SUB(TO_LOCALTIME(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP()), TIMESTAMP('0000-01-01 01:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'))) and (cs-uri-stem like '%%%.%.as%%%') GROUP BY TO_LOWERCASE(cs-uri-stem), TO_REAL(STRCAT(TO_STRING(sc-status), STRCAT('.', TO_STRING(sc-substatus)))) HAVING (COUNT(*)>2) order by status"

   rem CSV file parsing into text file
   C:\InfraLogsSync_dontdelete\Website_status\LogParser\LogParser.exe -rtp:-1 "select '<tr><td>', Date, '</td><td>', csUriStem, '</td><td>', Hits, '</td><td>', AvgTime, '</td><td>', MaxTime, '</td><td>', MinTime, '</td><td>', Status, '</td></tr>' into C:\Users\ilom08990\Desktop\Website_status\Website_status\123.txt from C:\Users\ilom08990\Desktop\Website_status\Website_status\123.csv"    

   rem VBScript execution
   cscript //nologo C:\Users\ilom08990\Desktop\Website_status\Website_status\Website_TimeTaken.vbs > C:\Users\ilom08990\Desktop\Website_status\Website_status\123.html
   ```
5. VBScript code:

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Dim objFile, strLine
   Dim objFSO, aline

   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objFile= objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\ilom08990\Desktop\Website_status\Website_status\123.txt", 1)

   Wscript.Echo "<tr><td><h1 style=color:blue> WebSite Perofrmance : 140 Server </h1></td></tr>"

   Wscript.Echo "<html>"
   Wscript.Echo "<head>"
   Wscript.Echo "<style> "
   Wscript.Echo "table"
   Wscript.Echo "{"
   Wscript.Echo "border-collapse:collapse;"
   Wscript.Echo "}"
   Wscript.Echo "table, td, th"
   Wscript.Echo "{"
   Wscript.Echo "border:1px solid black;"
   Wscript.Echo "}"
   Wscript.Echo "table"
   Wscript.Echo "{"
   Wscript.Echo "background-color:LIGHTBLUE;"
   Wscript.Echo "}"
   Wscript.Echo "</style>"
   Wscript.Echo "<head/>"
   Wscript.Echo "<body><table>"

   Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream
      strLine = objFile.readline
      Wscript.Echo "<p style=color:red>" & strLine & "</p>"
   Loop
   objFile.Close

   Wscript.Echo "</table>"
   Wscript.Echo "</body>"
   Wscript.Echo "</html>"
   ```

Comment: What is your question? Does your code not work as expected? If so, how are the actual results different from what you expected? Also, did you consider using PowerShell for this?

Comment: Hello Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: thanks for the response. With the current code i am unable to apply the condition format in html page. Please let me know how to implement the condition format using vbscript. My input file format is csv/text. current vbscript read the data line by line and print in html page with the table tags, it's not doing any other action. I just want read the text/csv file with vbscript and print the data in table format with the condition. When the condition fails that particular filed value color need to change. power shell  won't work in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think for a conditional format you need to remove the second `logparser` step and build the whole table in the VBScript. Something like this:

```
...
Wscript.Echo "<body><table>"

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = Split(objFile.ReadLine, ",")
  On Error Resume Next
  If IsNumeric(line(3)) Then
    If CDbl(line(3)) > 200 Then
      WScript.StdOut.Write "<tr style=""color:red""><td>"
    Else
      WScript.StdOut.Write "<tr><td>"
    End If
  Else
    WScript.StdOut.Write "<tr><td>"
  End If
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Join(a, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
Loop
objFile.Close

Wscript.Echo "</table>"
...
```

Comment: Hello Ansgar Wiechers, Thanks for the suggestions. With the help of your suggestion i fixed my issue and which is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ansgar Wiechers, for prompt support. Please find update code below

```
Option Explicit     
Dim objFile, strLine     
Dim objFSO, aline, i     
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
Set objFile= objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\InfraLogsSync_dontdelete\Website_status\test.txt", 1)     

Wscript.Echo "<tr><td><h1 style=color:blue> Fasttrack WebSite Perofrmance : 140 Server </h1></td></tr>"     

Wscript.Echo "<html>"     
Wscript.Echo "<head>"     
Wscript.Echo "<style> "     
Wscript.Echo "table"     
Wscript.Echo "{"     
Wscript.Echo "border-collapse:collapse;"     
Wscript.Echo "}"     
Wscript.Echo "table, td, th"     
Wscript.Echo "{"     
Wscript.Echo "border:1px solid black;"     
Wscript.Echo "}"     
Wscript.Echo "table"     
Wscript.Echo "{"     
Wscript.Echo "background-color:LIGHTBLUE;"     
Wscript.Echo "}"     
Wscript.Echo "</style>"     
Wscript.Echo "<head/>"     
Wscript.Echo "<body><table style=width:100%>"     

  Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream     
     strLine = objFile.readline     
     aline = Split(strLine, ",")     
         Wscript.Echo "<tr>"     

           For i = LBound(aline) to UBound(aline)     
             If IsNumeric(aline(3)) then                
                If CLng(aline(3)>200) then     
            Wscript.Echo "<td style='color:red;font-Weight:bold;'>" & aline(i) & "</td>"     
            Else     
            Wscript.Echo "<td>" & aline(i) & "</td>"     
                End If     
              Else     
          Wscript.Echo "<td style='font-Weight:bold;font-size: 20px;'>" & aline(i) & "</td>"     
              End If     
           Next     
     Wscript.Echo "</tr>"            

  Loop     
  objFile.Close     


Wscript.Echo "</table>"     
Wscript.Echo "</body>"     
Wscript.Echo "</html>"
```